# Vector member always zero size on call to member function that uses push_back to add to the vector member

Tags: c++, vector

What I am trying to do is add cards to a vector that is to be a Blackjack hand, but each time I enter the function that uses push_back to add a card to the vector, the vector starts out empty.  The problem is in my Hand class in the addCardToHand function, and the same issue is present in the same class in my showHand function.  I have whittled the code down as much as I could but still present a full working version with the issue.  I cannot figure out why my Hand class treats the hand as brand new every time I call a function in the class.  Please advise.

```
// Card.h
#ifndef CARD_H
#define CARD_H

#include <string>
#include <array>

class Card {
   private:
      int rank;
      int suit;
      int hardValue;
      int softValue;
      static const std::array<std::string,14> ranks;
      static const std::array<std::string,5> suits;
   public:
      Card();
      Card(int rank, int suit);
      int getHardValue() const;
      int getSoftValue() const;
      std::string toString() const;
};
#endif

// Card.cpp
#include "Card.h"

const std::array<std::string,14> Card::ranks {"","A","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10","J","Q","K"};
const std::array<std::string,5> Card::suits {"","C","D","H","S"};

Card::Card() : rank(0), suit(0) {
   hardValue = 0;
   softValue = 0;
}

Card::Card(int rank, int suit) : rank(rank), suit(suit) {
   if (rank == 1) {
      hardValue = 1;
      softValue = 11;
   }
   else if (rank <= 10) {
      hardValue = rank;
      softValue = rank;
   }
   else {
      hardValue = 10;
      softValue = 10;
   }
}

int Card::getHardValue() const {
   return hardValue;
}

int Card::getSoftValue() const {
   return softValue;
}

std::string Card::toString() const {
   return ranks[rank] + suits[suit];
}

// Shoe.h
#ifndef SHOE_H
#define SHOE_H

#include <vector>
#include <random>
#include "Card.h"

class Shoe {
   private:
      int numDecksInShoe;
      std::vector<Card> shoe;
      static int currentCard;
      static int maxDealCard;
      static const unsigned long int seed;
      static std::mt19937 randEng;
      void renewShoe();
   public:
      Shoe();
      explicit Shoe(int numDecksInShoe);
      std::vector<Card> getShoe() const;
      int getCurrentCard() const;
      int getMaxDealCard() const;
      void shuffle();
      Card dealCard();
};
#endif

// Shoe.cpp
#include <ctime>
#include "Shoe.h"

const unsigned long int Shoe::seed = static_cast<unsigned long int>(std::time(nullptr));
std::mt19937 Shoe::randEng(seed);
int Shoe::currentCard = 0;
int Shoe::maxDealCard = 51;

Shoe::Shoe() {
}

Shoe::Shoe(int decksInShoe) {
   numDecksInShoe = decksInShoe;
   int count = 0;

   for (int i = 0; i < numDecksInShoe; i++) {
      for (int suit = 4; suit >= 1; suit--) {
         for (int rank = 1; rank <= 13; rank++) {
            Card card(rank,suit);
            shoe.push_back(card);
            count += 1;
         }
      }
   }

   currentCard = 0;
   maxDealCard = count - 1;
}

std::vector<Card> Shoe::getShoe() const {
   return shoe;
}

int Shoe::getCurrentCard() const {
   return currentCard;
}

int Shoe::getMaxDealCard() const {
   return maxDealCard;
}

void Shoe::shuffle() {
   Card temp;
   std::uniform_int_distribution<int> deckDist(0,numDecksInShoe*52-1);
   int index;

   for (int i = 0; i < numDecksInShoe*52; i++) {
      do {
         index = deckDist(randEng);
      } while (index == i);

      temp = shoe[index];
      shoe[index] = shoe[i];
      shoe[i] = temp;
   }

   std::uniform_int_distribution<int> maxDeal(10,41);
   int tempMax = (numDecksInShoe-1)*52 - 1;
   maxDealCard = tempMax + 51 - maxDeal(randEng);
}

Card Shoe::dealCard() {
   if (currentCard == maxDealCard) {
      renewShoe();
   }
   Card dealCard = shoe[currentCard];
   currentCard += 1;
   return dealCard;
}

void Shoe::renewShoe() {
   Shoe newShoe(numDecksInShoe);
   shoe = newShoe.getShoe();
   shuffle();
}
```

here is my Hand class

```
// Hand.h
#ifndef HAND_H
#define HAND_H

#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include "Card.h"

class Hand {
   private:
      std::vector<Card> hand;
   public:
      Hand();
      std::vector<Card> getHand() const;
      void addCardToHand(Card card);
      void clearHand();
      Card revealBottomCard();
      std::string showHand() const;
      std::string peakHand() const;
};
#endif

// Hand.cpp
#include <iostream>
#include "Hand.h"

Hand::Hand() {
}

std::vector<Card> Hand::getHand() const {
   return hand;
}

void Hand::addCardToHand(Card card) {
   std::cout << card.toString() << std::endl;
   hand.push_back(card);
}

void Hand::clearHand() {
   hand.clear();
}

std::string Hand::showHand() const {
   std::string returnString = "";
   for (int i = hand.size()-1; i >= 1; i--) {
      returnString += hand[i].toString() + "\n";
   }
   returnString += "XX\n";

   return returnString;
}

std::string Hand::peakHand() const {
   std::string returnString = "";
   for (int i = hand.size()-1; i >= 0; i--) {
      returnString += hand[i].toString() + "\n";
   }
   return returnString;
}
```

here is the Table class that has the code that calls the Hand class functions

```
// Table.h
#ifndef TABLE_H
#define TABLE_H

#include "Shoe.h"
#include "Player.h"

class Table {
   private:
      Shoe shoe;
   public:
      explicit Table(Shoe shoe);
      Shoe getShoe() const;
      void clearHand(std::vector<Player> players);
      void dealHand(std::vector<Player> players);
};
#endif

// Table.cpp
#include <iostream>
#include "Table.h"

Table::Table(Shoe shoe) : shoe(shoe) {
}

Shoe Table::getShoe() const {
   return shoe;
}

void Table::clearHand(std::vector<Player> players) {
   for (Player &player : players) {
      player.getHand().clearHand();
   }
}

void Table::dealHand(std::vector<Player> players) {
   for (int i = 0; i <= 1; i++) {
      for (Player &player : players) {
         player.getHand().addCardToHand(shoe.dealCard());
      }
   }
}

// Player.h
#ifndef PLAYER_H
#define PLAYER_H

#include "Hand.h"

class Player {
   private:
      std::string name;
      Hand hand;
      double money;
   public:
      explicit Player(std::string name, double money = 1000.0);
      std::string getName() const;
      Hand getHand() const;
      double getMoney() const;
};
#endif

// Player.cpp
#include "Player.h"

Player::Player(std::string name, double money) : name(name), money(money) {
}

std::string Player::getName() const {
   return name;
}

Hand Player::getHand() const {
   return hand;
}

double Player::getMoney() const {
   return money;
}
```

and finally here is a short driver that runs and displays the issue

```
// blackjack testing
#include <iostream>
#include "Player.h"
#include "Table.h"

int main() {
   std::vector<Player> players {Player("Tom",1500.0),Player("Sue"),Player("Dave")};

   Shoe shoe1(6);
   Table table1(shoe1);

   table1.dealHand(players);

   for (Player player : players) {
      std::cout << player.getName() << "'s hand\n";
      std::cout << player.getHand().showHand() << "\n\n";
   }
}
```

The output is below.  I printed out the cards that were added to the hand vector (and then 'forgotten') and below that above the XX's, if everything were to work correctly you should see the 4, 5 and 6 of spades since I did not shuffle the deck.  The XX's are to simulate face down bottom card.

```
AS
2S
3S
4S
5S
6S
Tom's hand
XX


Sue's hand
XX


Dave's hand
XX
```

Sorry for dumping all this code in here, but I wanted to provide a full working solution and this is as small as I could get it.  Thanks for any help.

Comment: Did you mean to pass your arguments by reference?

Comment: i tried that solution after I copied and pasted all the code.  still same issue.  I have since changed my code though.

Comment: Have you tried running your code through a debugger?  You should identify the problematic code and post the minimal code required to reproduce the problem.  See [mre].

Comment: _"this is as small as I could get it"_ -- is that so? If you get rid of all the unused functions (like `clearHand` and shuffling), the problem disappears? If you replaced your vector of players with a single `Player` object, the problem disappears? If you get rid of the table and deal two cards directly from the `Shoe`, the problem disappears? If you get rid of the shoe, create two local `Card` variables and deal those cards to the player, the problem disappears? Somewhere along the line the problem might disappear, but did it? The goal is demonstrating the problem, not playing blackjack.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
player.getHand().addCardToHand(...);
```

`player.getHand()` returns a temporary `Hand` object that's a copy of `player.hand`. Then you add a card to that temporary object. Then that temporary object dies, added card and all. `player.hand` remains unchanged. This line of code is an elaborate no-op.

Answer (score 1):

To add on @Igor's answer, the best way to fix this should probably return a reference instead:

```
const Hand& Player::getHand() const {
   return hand;
}
```

I made this a `const` because returning a non-const could (potentially) allow you to break `const`ness of a constant `Player` object. That is just inviting potential bugs.

Because of this, you may want to add a non-const version too:

```
Hand& Player::getHand() {
   return hand;
}
```

Now you can't modify a const `Player` object, yet modify it properly when you need to.